# css for icon on the right of the text with correct fallback on overflow

Tags: html, css

please see this example http://jsfiddle.net/7trcV/
what I'm trying to achieve is ability to put an arbitrary icon to the right of the text in a way that text width is limited. In the example I posted the problem with the second (short text) is - the icon is displayed detached from the text.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so you want to display icon right next to the text or am i wrong..? I think i dont get the question...

Comment: Yep, you understood it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/7trcV/5/

I gave the `.content` a right padding and set the icon as it's background.

---

Ok, try this http://jsfiddle.net/7trcV/6/ it should have sorted out your underline issues. I'm not addressing the clickable icon because that's a completely different requirement from your original question.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately that has a number of glitches (no underline on hover in chrome, double underline in ff3.6, a mess around the icon in ff3.6, etc) + doesn't allow me to put a separate clickable icon in the end (which is also one of the usecases)

Comment: it's still a mess in ff3.6 but that's the best possible thing i guess

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry i did not look at your code properly for the first time... problem here is absolutely positioned icon which need to be floated next to your spans like this: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7trcV/4/)

after you do this you must set max-width of that span to be width of container-width of icon... hope this will help

Comment: sorry, now i don't quite get your answer. .content is already inline-block, setting it to block doesn't change anything to me

Comment: you set   max-width: 160px; on the content, but I can't do that, cuz I don't know the absolute width unfortunately

Comment: but you have those wrapping divs 200px width... so you know that there is 200px-iconwidth space fot text or not?

Comment: Ok i think i have the best one... make the icon background of the span(positioned right center) and then make 20px(or icon-width) padding on the right side... cool and simple here - http://jsfiddle.net/7trcV/7/

Comment: thanks, that's essentially the same thing as MrMisterMan suggested above

Comment: yet it is, i did not noticed his answer i just remembered how I do it... anyway gl

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to find the width of the span, and have the icon positions right next to it.

Exmaple here: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/KCttp/

Comment: If possible I'd prefer avoiding js

Comment: Yeah it's always good to try and avoid js. However I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want without it. Personally, I think it looks better with the icon always on the right.